# How to select a specific HTML element from a for loop in a Django template?

Tags: javascript, html, django, for-loop, queryselector

I am trying to create a button that hides and displays only the specific `HTML` elements that are in the same div with it through `JavaScript`. All the divs are within a `Django` template for loop and display different information. Right now, I am using a `querySelector` to select the id, but that is not correct because it selects the first element it finds with that id.

`html`:

```
<div>
        {% for post in page_obj.object_list %}
            <div class = "individual_posts">
                <a href="{% url 'username' post.user %}"><h5 id="p_user" class = "post_user">{{ post.user }}</h5></a>
                <h6 id = "post_itself">{{ post.post }}</h6>
                <h6 id="date_and_time" class = "post_elements">{{ post.date_and_time }}</h6>
                <h6 id="likes" class = "post_elements">{{ post.likes }}&#x1F44D;</h6>
                {% if post.user == request.user %}
                    <button class="edit_button" value="{{ post.id }}">Edit</button>
                {% endif %}
                <textarea class="textarea" id="edit_area"></textarea>
                <button class="edit_save" id="save">Save</button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

`javascript`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //hide the textarea
    const editingTextareas = document.querySelectorAll(".textarea");
    for (const textarea of editingTextareas){
        textarea.style.display = 'none';
    }
    //hide the save buttons for the textarea
    const saveButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".edit_save");
    for (const s_button of saveButtons){
        s_button.style.display = 'none';
    }
    //adds the click to the edit buttons
    const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit_button');
    for (const button of editButtons) {
      id = button.value;
      button.addEventListener('click', () => edit_email(id));
    }
  });
  
function edit_email(id){
    document.querySelector('#post_itself').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#date_and_time').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#likes').style.display = 'none';
    const edit_area = document.querySelector('#edit_area');
    edit_area.style.display = 'block';
    const save = document.querySelector('#save');
    save.style.display = 'block';

    //get post
    fetch(`/edit/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(post => {
        edit_area.innerHTML = `${post.post}`;
    })

    //save the post
    fetch(`/edit/${id}`,{
        method: 'POST',
        post: JSON.stringify({
            post: edit_area.value
        })
    })
}
```

Will I have to run each `HTML` element through a for loop like I do when the `DOM` is first loaded to hide the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sharing the same id for multiple elements. According to MDN,

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors

To fix this for your case, append the post ID to the element ID so each ID is unique and can be queried individually. E.g `<h6 id = "post_itself-{{post.id}}">{{ post.post }}</h6>`, then the JS side should be:

```
document.querySelector(`#post_itself-${id}`).style.display = 'none';
```

Do that for all repeated IDs. I'll advise you to store the element in a variable so you don't have to repeatedly query the same element

```
const postItselfEl = document.querySelector(`#post_itself-${id}`)
```

Comment: this sort of works. The user gets the choice of which button to press, and each button is within a different div (and all the other elements I'm trying to get access to are different), but no matter which button the user presses, the display and none work for the bottommost div, not the one that goes with the button the user pressed. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You'll also need to update `id="likes"` to `id="likes-{{post.id}}"`. Then update the JS side to query based on the id too e.g `document.querySelector(`#likes-${id}`)`. 
Same for `date_and_time`

Comment: I did that, and I am still receiving the problem that I explained above. I also added a console.log that will log the id when the button is pressed, and the number in the console is the same no matter which button is clicked (for a particular user). I think whatever is causing that is also causing this problem. Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: Inspect the values of the edit buttons if they indeed have the right post ids.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by passing in the id to the event listener, but if I use ```edit_button = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);``` to get access to the edit button to hide it, I receive this error: ```Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#3' is not a valid selector.``` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The code snippet you pasted already passed the id to the event listener, so I guess you did something different. Use exactly what you have in the snippet, in addition to my answer here and it should work. By the way, `'#3' is not a valid selector` is because you're using a number as a selector instead of a string. Also your edit button has a class and no ID, so that won't work. 
Just go with the snippet you pasted